# How can import oracle dump into oracle XE 11

Tags: oracle, import, oracle11g

I have got the `oracle 9i database dump` and i have installed `oracle 11 XE` on home.

I have installed on Ubuntu `14.04`

I also have installed `sql developer`

I don't know how the dump was created but this is the log file

```
Connected to: Oracle9i Release 9.2.0.8.0 - Production
JServer Release 9.2.0.8.0 - Production
Export done in WE8MSWIN1252 character set and AL16UTF16 NCHAR character set
server uses AL32UTF8 character set (possible charset conversion)

About to export specified users ...
. exporting pre-schema procedural objects and actions
. exporting foreign function library names for user JOHN 
. exporting PUBLIC type synonyms
. exporting private type synonyms
. exporting object type definitions for user JOHN
About to export JOHN's objects ...
. exporting database links
. exporting sequence numbers
. exporting cluster definitions
. about to export JOHN's tables via Conventional Path ...
```

I am new to oracle so not sure how to import it.
Is there any GUI tools for that. Can i do in sql developer 4

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use SQLPLUS with `imp` command.

To import, create a shell script called `importdb.sh`:

```
sqlplus sys/sys@localhost as sysdba @Script.sql

imp asset_dw/asset_dw   FILE=asset_dw.dmp fromuser=asset_dw
```

Script.sql located in the same directory, `asset_dw` is an Oracle user, also the DB:

```
DROP  USER  asset_dw  CASCADE;
CREATE USER  asset_dw   IDENTIFIED BY asset_dw;   
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES TO asset_dw;
quit;
```

You will need asset_dw.dmp in the same directory

Or you can try: [this](http://learnoraclewithmax.blogspot.com/2012/04/export-import-dump-oracle-10g11g-linux.html)